# Cakephp request action gives me a never ending request loop

Tags: php, cakephp, element

I have an element with a requestAction but it gives me a never ending request loop.

For example:

This is my element

```
<?php $plans = $this->requestAction('profile/Plans'); ?>
<?php foreach($plans as $plan): ?>

    <div class="notificationsmall <?php echo $plan['sections']['lable']; ?>">
        <p><b><?php echo $plan['plans']['plan_title']; ?></b></p>
        <p><?php echo $plan['plans']['plan_description']; ?></p>
    </div>  
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And this is the function that. Its in the "profile" controller

```
function Plans($id = Null){ 
    $this->set('plans', $this->Plan->Query('SELECT * FROM plans, sections WHERE plans.user_id='.$id.' AND sections.id=plans.section_id'));
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the first piece of code the profile/plans view? If so, you get an infinite loop because the view calls the profile/plans action again, comes back to the same point in the view and so on.

Judging by the code I think you have some misunderstanding on how elements work. You should use the requestAction when you need to insert the element, not inside the element itself.

(I agree with Dunhamzzz that requestAction should be avoided, but sometimes it's not possible. You should consider if using actual elements would work in this case.)

Comment: So i have to use the same functions in multiple controllers?

Comment: If you use elements that use data from the database, then yes. If you use requestAction, then no. RequestAction's point is that you call an action as if you'd called that page directly from the browser. It's like a page inside a page. Ultimately it all depends on what you're trying to do, so we might be talking about different things right now.

Comment: This is example is so simple that using the RequestAction is definitely not the "cake" way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using RequestAction! Avoid it at all costs. You should create a method in your Plans model that basically returns the contents of the query you're doing, eg

```
function getByUserId($userId) {
    return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Plan.user_id' => $userId)));
}
```

Then in your action, just do `$this->set('plans', $this->Plan->getByUserId($userId));`